# Cannot read property 'target' of undefined / TypeError: event is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I want to upload an image by clicking on the image element with `id='IBrowse'` but an error occurs when I click on the that image.

> Cannot read property 'target' of undefined(…) (in Chrome)
>
> TypeError: event is undefined (in Firefox)

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback pull-right bordered">
    <img id="HImg" src="~/b/b.jpg" style="height: 120px; max-width: 100%; width: 280px; position:relative", class="img-responsive" />
    <img id="IBrowse" src="~/a/a.png" style="position: absolute; width: 20%; top: 5%; left: 17%;" />

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Img, new { @class = "form-control has-feedback-left file btntag", style = "display: none;", @onchange = "open(e)", @type = "file", placeholder = "Upload Image" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Img, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

```js
$(function () {
    $('#IBrowse').on('click', function () {
        $('#Img').trigger('onchange');
    });
});
```

> onchange event code

```
<script>
        var IsUpdate = false;
        var open = function (event) {
            var input = event.target;
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function () {

                var dataURL = reader.result;
                var output = document.getElementById('ImgHTMLElement');
                output.src = dataURL;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        };
    </script>
```

Also, the CSS is not working:

```
#IBrowse:hover {
    width: 23%;
}
```

Comment: You should consider using `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead of using the FileReader

Answer (score 1):

I never use `onchange` so maybe there is a way to do this there. However, I would simply drop the `onchange="....."` and use a handler like this:

```
<script>
  var IsUpdate = false; 
  $('#Img').on('change', function(event) {
      var input = event.target;
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function() {

        var dataURL = reader.result;
        var output = document.getElementById('ImgHTMLElement');
        output.src = dataURL;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); 
  });
</script>
```

As for your css issue, the problem is that you define an inline style like:

`<img id="HImg" src="~/b/b.jpg" style="height: 120px; max-width: 100%; width: 280px; position:relative", class="img-responsive" />`

The css rule  `#IBrowse:hover {width: 23%;}` is applied, but it will not override the inline style setting which has a higher precedence. You can overcome that by

#### Option 1) Preferred method

Move your inline style to a css rule instead of inline like this:

```
#IBrowse{
    position: absolute; 
    width: 20%; 
    top: 5%; 
    left: 17%;
}
#IBrowse:hover {
    width: 23%; 
}
```

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/d160vLqm/60/)

---

#### Option 2)

Leave the inline style and add `!important` to the hover css rule like this:

```
#IBrowse:hover {
    width: 23% !important; 
}
```

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/d160vLqm/61/)

Comment: @TittiTowel Youre welcome, dont forget to close the question if its resolved now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code but if you want your `open` function to be passed the event object you should specify it as `event` rather than `e` in the `onchange` attribute definition, since this is not an assignment to the the event itself, but a callback function body that already has been passed the `event` parameter:

```
@onchange = "open(event)"
```